# Timeline tab; lag between Timer Fired events

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Per the screenshot below, I'm seeing Timer Fired events, which individually don't take that much time (~1.5 ms each) but there seems to be a lag in between them that I'd like to understand.

They all seem to have a function call in lidar.js:19. This lidar.js file is compressed and therefore not readable to me. I'm also not the developer for this file, but would like to tell them where to look in order to reduce this lag. At the moment, they're claiming that this lag doesn't exist.

[image: lag between timer fired events]

Answer (score 0):

> Per the screenshot below, I'm seeing Timer Fired events, which individually don't take that much time (~1.5 ms each) but there seems to be a lag in between them that I'd like to understand.

From the screenshot it looks like old timer gets removed while processing  setTimout callback function at lidar.js:19 (actual removal is lidar.js:85) and a new one is created at lidar.js:87. If the next Timer Fired event corresponds to just scheduled timer it will fire not sooner than a [minimal delay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout#Minimummaximum_delay_and_timeout_nesting) even if you call setTimeout(function(){...}, 0); According to the document the delay will be at least 4ms. This might be the reason why you see the lag between Timer Fired events.

> This lidar.js file is compressed and therefore not readable to me.

You can pretty print source code in that file by pressing "{}" button in the bottom left corner in Sources panel.